# MySql Group and sum sales by by month for each departments across the year joining multiple tables

Tags: sql, mariadb-10.3

I've been trying to achieve the following to no avail. Any help will be appreciated.

**Departments** - *Departments within an organization*

| id | department_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Process Consulting |
| 2 | Technical Consulting |
| 3 | Administrative Unit |

**Services** - *Each service rendered is mapped to a department*

| id | service_name | department_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Project management | 1 |
| 2 | Video production | 2 |
| 3 | Training | 2 |
| 4 | Facility Rental | 3 |

**Transactions** - *Each transaction is mapped to a service*

| id | transaction_amount | service_id | transaction_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 | 1 | 2021-02-04 |
| 2 | 3000 | 4 | 2021-01-01 |
| 3 | 1500 | 2 | 2021-03-14 |
| 4 | 3500 | 2 | 2021-03-20 |

**The result I would like to achieve**

| department_id | department_name | year_summary (Jan - Dec separated by comma) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Process Consulting | 0,2000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 |
| 2 | Technical Consulting | 0,0,5000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 |
| 3 | Administrative Unit | 3000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 |

Comment: Which version of mysql you are using?

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur Version 10.3.28-MariaDB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want conditional aggregation at two levels.  The first is a summary by department and month:

```
select d.id, d.department_name, month(transaction_date) as mon,
       sum(t.transaction_amount) as amount
from departments d left join
     services s
     on s.department_id = d.id left join
     transactions t
     on t.service_id = s.id  
where t.transaction_date >= '2021-01-01' and
      t.transaction_date < '2022-01-01'   
group by d.id, d.department_name;
```

The second then aggregates that in the format you want:

```
select id, department_name,
       concat_ws(',',
                 max(case when mon = 1 then amount else 0 end),
                 max(case when mon = 2 then amount else 0 end),
                 . . .   -- fill in the rest of the months
                 max(case when mon = 12 then amount else 0 end)
                ) as year_summary
from (select d.id, d.department_name, month(transaction_date) as mon,
             sum(t.transaction_amount) as amount
      from departments d left join
           services s
           on s.department_id = d.id left join
           transactions t
           on t.service_id = s.id  
      where t.transaction_date >= '2021-01-01' and
            t.transaction_date < '2022-01-01'   
      group by d.id, d.department_name
     ) dm
group by id, department_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you have already got your answer I am sharing here another one since it's already prepared:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table Departments(id int, department_name varchar(100));
 insert into Departments values(1,  'Process Consulting');
 insert into Departments values(2,  'Technical Consulting');
 insert into Departments values(3,  'Administrative Unit');  
 
 create table Services (id int, service_name varchar(100), department_id int);
 insert into Services values(1, 'Project management',   1);
 insert into Services values(2, 'Video production'  ,   2);
 insert into Services values(3, 'Training'      ,   2);
 insert into Services values(4, 'Facility Rental'   ,   3);
 
 create table Transactions(id int, transaction_amount int, service_id int, transaction_date date);
 insert into Transactions values(1, 2000,   1,  '2021-02-04');
 insert into Transactions values(2, 3000,   4,  '2021-01-01');
 insert into Transactions values(3, 1500,   2,  '2021-03-14');
 insert into Transactions values(4, 3500,   2,  '2021-03-20');
```

Query (with common table expression and group_concat() ):

```
 with Calendar as
   (
   SELECT 1 mon UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL
   SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL
   SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
   )
   , d as (select * from Calendar cross join Departments )
   , t as (select d.id,d.department_name ,month(transaction_date)mon, sum(transaction_amount)amountsum  from Departments d inner join Services s on d.id=s.department_id
 inner join Transactions t on s.id=t.service_id
 group by  d.id,d.department_name 
              )
              
 select d.id,d.department_name,group_concat(coalesce(amountsum,0) order by d.mon)  year_summary
 from d left join t on d.id=t.id and t.mon=d.mon
 group by d.id
```

Output:

| id | department_name | year_summary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Process Consulting | 0,2000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 |
| 2 | Technical Consulting | 0,0,5000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 |
| 3 | Administrative Unit | 3000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f4e630150bb604215915466598f20bb4)*